# vue.js, vuetify scroll event not firing when using css scroll snap

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

UPDATE dropped this approach and went with vue-awesome-swiper script

I"m been stuck on this for days. Basically I want to use css scroll snap and I want to monitor scroll also.

In this basic example with just javascript it works fine scroll event fires and div snaps with css. The other pen below with vue.js does not and that is my problem. Losing hair about this... any help appreciated!

https://codepen.io/travis-pancakes/pen/pGYOZK?editors=0011

```js
var i = 0;
function Onscrollfnction(event) {    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = i;
  i = i + 1;

    };
```

```css
/* setup */
html, body, .holster {
  height: 100%;
}
.holster {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
  font-family: monospace;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  overflow: auto;
  outline: 1px dashed lightgray;
  flex: none;
}

.container.x {
  width: 100%;
  height: 128px;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
}

.container.y {
  width: 256px;
  height: 256px;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
}
/* scroll-snap */
.x.mandatory-scroll-snapping {
  scroll-snap-type: x mandatory;
}

.y.mandatory-scroll-snapping {
  scroll-snap-type: y mandatory;
}

.x.proximity-scroll-snapping {
  scroll-snap-type: x proximity;
}

.y.proximity-scroll-snapping {
  scroll-snap-type: y proximity;
}

.container > div {
  text-align: center;
  scroll-snap-align: center;
  flex: none;
}

.x.container > div {
  line-height: 128px;
  font-size: 64px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 128px;
}

.y.container > div {
  line-height: 256px;
  font-size: 128px;
  width: 256px;
  height: 256px;
}
/* appearance fixes */
.y.container > div:first-child {
  line-height: 1.3;
  font-size: 64px;
}
/* coloration */
.container > div:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #87EA87;
}

.container > div:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: #87CCEA;
}
```

```html
<div><p>Scrolled <span id="demo">0</span> times.</p></div>
<div class="container y mandatory-scroll-snapping" onscroll="Onscrollfnction();" dir="ltr">
  <div>Y Mand. LTR</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
  <div>5</div>


</div>
```

The vue.js, vuetify version does not
https://codepen.io/travis-pancakes/pen/BMbqPq?editors=1111

```js
new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: function(){
        return {
            i: 0
        }
    },
    created () {
  },
    methods: {
      Onscrollfnction (event) {    
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = this.i;
          this.i = this.i + 1;
          console.log('i  ', i)
      }
    }
});
```

```css
/* setup */
html, body, .holster {
  height: 100%;
}
.holster {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
  font-family: monospace;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  overflow: auto;
  outline: 1px dashed lightgray;
  flex: none;
}

.container.x {
  width: 100%;
  height: 128px;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
}

.container.y {
  width: 256px;
  height: 256px;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
}
/* scroll-snap */
.x.mandatory-scroll-snapping {
  scroll-snap-type: x mandatory;
}

.y.mandatory-scroll-snapping {
  scroll-snap-type: y mandatory;
}

.x.proximity-scroll-snapping {
  scroll-snap-type: x proximity;
}

.y.proximity-scroll-snapping {
  scroll-snap-type: y proximity;
}

.container > div {
  text-align: center;
  scroll-snap-align: center;
  flex: none;
}

.x.container > div {
  line-height: 128px;
  font-size: 64px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 128px;
}

.y.container > div {
  line-height: 256px;
  font-size: 128px;
  width: 256px;
  height: 256px;
}
/* appearance fixes */
.y.container > div:first-child {
  line-height: 1.3;
  font-size: 64px;
}
/* coloration */
.container > div:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #87EA87;
}

.container > div:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: #87CCEA;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
    <!-- could use v-scroll="Onscrollfnction" with vuetify" --->
<div class="container y mandatory-scroll-snapping" 
     v-on:scroll.native="Onscrollfnction" dir="ltr">
  <div>Y Mand. LTR</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
  <div>5</div>
</div>
<p>Scrolled <span id="demo">0</span> times.</p>

</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

vue-awesome-swiper does the functionality I'm going for